# Naming associative arrays within PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I currently face the following problem:

With laravel I want to dynamically create and seed my permissions config. I currently have it hardcoded the following way (within `Config/permissions.php`):

```
<?php
return [
 'core' => [
         'permissions' => [
             [
                 'name' => 'name',
                 'description' => 'desc',
             ],
             [
                 'name' => 'name',
                 'description' => 'desc',
             ],
         ],

 ],
];
```

With laravel I am able to use the ["dot"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#accessing-configuration-values) notation. Accessing my config files is a breeze, as I can do:

```
\Config::get('permissions.core');
```

However, I want to generate the above code dynamically. I've tried recreating it it manually but I always face the problem that I cant name my first array, which results to the following:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["core"]=>
    array(0) {
    }

}
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["example"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

If I want to use the *dot notation* on this array:

```
\Config::get('permissions.core');
```

I get an undefined index error. My question specifically is, how do I recreate the 'hardcoded' array? How do I give my first array a name ('core') so I can get the 'hardcoded' result?

Thanks fin advance.

Comment: Show us how you generates the code dynamically.

Comment: Share the code on how you're trying to do this. Secondly the config helper would only work with the config file array. Generating the same array dynamically wouldn't enable to you access it the same way since you can't use the config facade and helper with that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I feel stupid now. I asked the question because I was banging my head against the table (not literally) and forgot how basic arrays worked. I hoped to get a new insight when posting. All it took was:

```
        $config = \Config::get('permissions');
        $modules = //retrieve modules
        foreach($modules as $module){
            $config[$module->getSlug()] = array();
        }
        \Config::set('permissions', $config);
```

Which results in:

```
array(2) {
  ["core"]=>
  //the part below is from another method
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "permission_1"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "permission_2"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "permission_3"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "permission_4"
  }
  ["module"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```